# Axios response returns HTML

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem in getting some data in my database. It returns HTML data.

```
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n    <head>\n      …>\n    \x3Cscript src="/js/app.js">\x3C/script>\n</html>\n', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…},…}
```

And I am only requesting an authenticated user's username. Here are my codes:

Vue.JS 3.0.0 Vuex

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/accounts',
});

async getCurrentUser(context, payload) {
            try {
                const response = await api.get('/accounts/get-user');
                console.log(response)
                context.commit('setUserLogged', response.data.current_user);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
```

Getters:

```
mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('getCurrentUser')
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getUserLogged']),
    isLogged(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("auth_token")) {
             return true
        }
    return false
    },
},
```

My AuthController:

```
public function get_logged_user(){
        $user_logged = auth()->user();
        return response()->json(['current_user' => $user_logged, 'result' => 'Success' ]);
    }
```

And my route:

```
Route::prefix('accounts')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/get-user',[AuthController::class, 'get_logged_user'])->name('get_logged_user');
    // other routes here...
})
```

I already added the bootstrap.js required codes:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set content type.
According Axios's https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86
You need to add `data:{}`

```js
axios.get('url', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data:{}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve your issue with a **server-side approach**. You can create a `ForceJsonMiddleware` to automatically add the required header to force your Laravel API to return JSON.

Here is an example of middleware that I use in most of my projects:

```php
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then, depending on your needs, here's how you should register it in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

**You want to apply it to all routes of your Laravel API ?**:

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        ...
        ForceJsonMiddleware::class, // <-- add it here
        HandleCors::class
    ];
```

**You want to apply it only to certain routes ?**
Create an alias :

```php
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ....
        'forcejson' => ForceJsonMiddleware::class, // <-- add it here
    ];
```

And use it on your route file :

```php
Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'testMethod'])->middleware('forcejson');
```